# Allow user to sign in by Azure AD username and password

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-active-directory, jwt

In my controller I hard-coded a username and password. Now I want to allow the user to login with his/her Azure AD username and password.

```
        public IActionResult Login([FromBody] LoginModel user)
        {
            if (user == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Invalid client request");
            }
            if (user.UserName == "johndoe" && user.Password == "def@MKK")
            {
                var secretKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("justAsecretKey"));
                var signinCredentials = new SigningCredentials(secretKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

                var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName)
                };
                
                var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    audience: "http://api.azurewebsites.net",
                    issuer: "http://api.azurewebsites.net",
                    claims: claims,
                    expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60),
                    signingCredentials: signinCredentials
                );

                var results = new
                {
                    token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                    expiration = token.ValidTo
                };
                return Ok(results);
            }
            else
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }
        }
```

Comment: So are you looking for a demo about get access tokens by password flow and client_assertion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Solution:

1. I got rid of the hardcoded User
2. Added Credentials validation
3. Provide the Azure AD Configurations
4. Set the scopes/api permissions
5. AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword
6. Return the Tokens and other info when succesful
7. Otherwise return BadRequest or Unauthorized

   ```
   public ActionResult Login([FromBody] UserModel user)
   {
   if (user == null)
   {
       var results = new
       {
           Message = "Invalid client request"
       };
       return BadRequest(results);
   }

   if (user.UserName != "" && user.Password != "")
   {
       try
       {
           string clientId = Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
           string tenantId = Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"];
           string authority = Configuration["AzureAd:Authority"]; 

           string[] scopes = new string[] { "User.Read", "Directory.AccessAsUser.All", "User.Invite.All" };

           IPublicClientApplication app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
               .WithAuthority(authority)
               .WithTenantId(tenantId)
               .Build();

           var securePassword = new SecureString();
           foreach (char c in user.Password.ToCharArray())  // you should fetch the password
               securePassword.AppendChar(c);  // keystroke by keystroke

           var tokens = app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes, user.UserName, securePassword).ExecuteAsync().Result;

           graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
               new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(x =>
               {
                   x.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                       "Bearer", tokens.AccessToken);

                   return Task.FromResult(0);
               }));

           var results = new
           {
               ExpiresOn = tokens.ExpiresOn.LocalDateTime,
               AccessToken = tokens.AccessToken,
               Token = tokens.IdToken,
               Environment = tokens.Account.Environment,
               AccountId = tokens.Account.HomeAccountId
           };
           return Ok(results);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           var results = new
           {
               Message = ex.Message
           };

           return Unauthorized(results);
       }
   }
   else
   {
       var results = new
       {
           Message = "Username or password isn't valid."
       };

       return Unauthorized(results);
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi @Tassisto. what were there in  Configuration["AzureAd:Authority"]. i am able to authenticate without it as well